# Smart Routing while connecting to the k8s cluster from "outside"

Tags: kubernetes, networking, devops

I would like to get your advice about whether the following setup is available in kubernetes.

I have a kubernetes cluster (in the private cloud, not an AWS or something) running series of pods which serve as "gateway" of my application. These are java applications that I'm responsible for and I have a full control over them. But I do assume that in production there will be an easy way to "scale out" the gateway instances when needed.

By design, these gateways will receive connections from the "agents" - applications running outside of my kubernetes cluster on various client machines.These apps are also part of the product (my team will write them) but there can be many of them (maybe millions).The interconnection is supposed to be done by web sockets (wss) so that each agent, upon startup, will connect to the gateway and will receive commands from the server via the bi-directional connection, the agents will execute these commands and will respond back to the gateway. If there is a disconnection because of an unstable network, the agent should issue a new web socket connection.

The client application on which the agent will be installed will have an "identifier" (like client id). If the client application by itself will be hosted on N different machines it will configure N different agents (one agent per client server), all of them will share the same "client id".

Now here comes an interesting part:

*I would like all the agents sharing the same client id to be handled by the same gateway instance pod. The gateway could also manage multiple clients but a client should be managed by only one gateway.*

The typical usage for my scenario is: I'm getting a command from the operator of my application that sounds like "for all agents having client id 123456 run the command X, for instance, "count the files in the folder on the client machine that the agent is configured to watch over", merge the results and return a unified result to the operator".
The operator of my application will have a UI and from his/her point of view the flow should be synchronous.
So In ideal I would like to call only one gateway and not all the available gateways one by one for each call like this.

I have two possible "directions" in mind:

**Direction 1:**

Ideally when an agent starts and connects to some kind of load balancer, I can pass the client id as a connection header so that kubernetes would be able to "route" the request to the gateway, however the list of gateways can be dynamic (scale out /in) so I can maintain a registry of gateways or something, but then I don't know how to do such a clever routing at the level of kubernetes.

[image: Direction 1 schema]

**Direction 2:**

Another option is exposing the "IPs" of all the gateways to all the agents so that each agent will contact "by http" to "any gateway" over the load balancer and will ask something like "what is the IP of the gateway that can serve my client id"? The gateway will calculate the response based on internally maintained registry (shared between all the running gateway instances at the moment) in some kind of database and will respond with something like "you should talk to IP "1.2.3.4" so that the agent could establish WS connection directly to "1.2.3.4". But then again, how do I expose "IP per pod of gateway from the k8s standpoint"?

[image: Direction 2 schema]

Last point that I think should be a requirement is that if I use some kind of routing logic in the first direction, I would like to establish a "direct" WS connection (probably over IP tables or something) so that the data won't be transferred to the load balancer and only then to one of the gateways because, since the WS connections are persistent, the load balancer will quickly become a bottleneck by itself.

**I would like to know whether kubernetes can support such a "hybrid" setup and if it does, what k8s components should I define to make this scenario (any of directions) work?**

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand your request but have you looked at the contour ingress controller, from what I recall it is very feature rich.

Comment: I'm pretty new to the kubernetes ecosystem (a kind of casual user, being primarily a developer)... So I'll definitely take a look into contour, thanks.

Comment: IIUC your agent would connect to a `loadbalancer` that would be backed up by some kind of `Ingress` controller that would have implemented a logic behind the routing to the respective services. Have you seen by any chance [traefik's header based routing](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/routers/#rule) or [ambassador's header based routing](https://www.getambassador.io/docs/edge-stack/latest/topics/using/headers/headers/#header-based-routing)?

Answer (score 0):

If your agents can set gateway id or name in the request url then you can use ALB and route the request to specific gateway service in the cluster. You have to define path based rules in ALB.

Or you can set trarfik ingress controller behind load balancer which can route traffic to specific gateway service.

Comment: ALB is something AWS specific right? I'm running in a private cloud not managed by any of the cloud providers. When gateway instances scale out, is it possible to update routing rules "dynamically"?

Comment: Gateways are pods in you case..right? If so then you have to create service in front and group them using labels. This way scaling of pods will work.